# How to create preconfigured fake debit card, for testing paying without paypal's account in sandbox?

Tags: paypal, sandbox, credit-card

I dont want to put real visa card information for testing paying in sandbox.
Is any way to create preconfigured card for testing?

Answer (score 8):

Any Visa card adhering to the Luhn algorithm will work.
However, there are a few things to consider.

1. If 'Negative Review' is enabled on the Sandbox test account, using a certain amount, CVV code or expiry date can trigger a decline. 'Negative review' is intended to test error scenario's, and depends on you setting a certain CVV code or amount in order to trigger an error response. To avoid this, I would recommend always using a CVV code of '000', which will always succeed.
2. Not all card types are supported in Sandbox. E.g. Amex may be troublesome. It's best to test with Visa.
3. PayPal Sandbox doesn't connect to any processors, and as such there is no actual card validation taking place. Any expiry date in combination with any card number (providing the card type is acceptable) and any CVV code will work.

For example the following card numbers would be great to test with;

Card type: VISA
Expiry date (all cards): any date in the future. E.g. 05/2018
CVV code (all cards): 000

Any Visa card number from http://www.darkcoding.net/credit-card-numbers/

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of [test credit card number](https://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=test%20credit&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=test%20credit%20card%20numbers)s to use. No need to use a real one.